# Exporting transparent .png in R and importing into Illustrator. MacOS vs. Windows

Tags: r, png, adobe-illustrator

When I export a transparent .png in R using MacOS, the background shows up as transparent when I import it into Adobe Illustrator (which is what I want).

```
png('example.png',bg='transparent')
```

But when I export a transparent .png in R using Windows, the background shows up as white in Illustrator. Why (and how) do the two operating systems encode the .png differently?

Comment: Interesting. I manage to replicate that on Adobe Illustrator CS6 (win) as well. The transparent background is showing on other applications though (e.g. photoshop, windows preview)